# ¿Como le hago para cargar mas de una fila en el DropDownList/Combobox en C#? Sin que el value deje de tener el id

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio

Ok, quiero ver si hay una forma en la cual pueda hacer que el dropdownlist pueda desplegar los datos de mas de una fila en C#, el problema es que solo he encontrado un método pero dicho método hace que puedas cargar mas de una fila en el desplegable, sin embargo el value hace que sea el mismo, cuando a mi me interesaría que fuera en este caso el id. De tal forma que el usuario vea los datos escritos, pero el ID este guardado en el value, para hacer las operaciones de Insert/Update de SQL server. Aquí muestro mi codigo que estaba llevando acabo. Muchas gracias. :)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = "Mi conexion de base de datos";

    cn.Open();

    string querybox;
    querybox = "SELECT ALUMNOID, ALUMNONOMBRE, ALUMNOAPPATERNO FROM ALUMNOS;";

    SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(querybox, cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adaptador.Fill(ds);
    DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString();
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Qué significa *que el dropdownlist pueda desplegar los datos de mas de una fila*? Cómo es tu html? Cómo se ve el resultado? Cómo debería verse? No es muy claro lo que preguntas

Comment: datavaluefield es el nombre del campo de donde queres que se tomen los id, no el valor del campo. De igual forma datatextfield es el nombre del campo de donde queres que se tomen los textos a mostrar, no el valor de un campo... arregla eso y listo...

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Mi conexion de base de datos";

        cn.Open();

        string querybox;
        querybox = "SELECT ALUMNOID, ALUMNONOMBRE, ALUMNOAPPATERNO FROM ALUMNOS;";

        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(querybox, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ComboBox DropDownList1 = new ComboBox();
        adaptador.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        DropDownList1.DisplayMember = "ALUMNONOMBRE";
        DropDownList1.ValueMember = "ALUMNOID";
        
        cn.Close();
    }
```